# Generated Avatar Images?

Tags: image, generator

StackOverflow, and other sites like Wordpress, use default avatar images that seem generated procedurally... (or maybe it's just my imagination :D ). Is there a library to do this?

Comment: You're looking for an [identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) generator; check out [jdenticon](https://jdenticon.com/), [tinygraphs](https://www.tinygraphs.com/), or the similar

Comment: I have created a [**simple PHP class**](https://github.com/saidbakr/FoxIdenticon) for that.

Comment: For a more styled solution, https://infiniteavatarai.com/ will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

The site http://en.gravatar.com/ will generate these images for you.  If the user doesn't have an image uploaded already, the default image can be set to "[identicon](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)" which generates a unique image for that person.